# C# DeserializeObject of OpenApiDocument with IOpenApiAny

Tags: c#, swagger, deserialization, openapi

The type namespace is `Microsoft.OpenApi.Models`.

First I got my service exposing an `OpenApiDocument` at the end point with the following code:

```
            string serializedOpenApiDocument = this.document.Serialize(OpenApiSpecVersion.OpenApi3_0, OpenApiFormat.Json);
            JToken openApiDocument = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<JToken>(
                serializedOpenApiDocument,
                new JsonSerializerSettings()
                {
                    MetadataPropertyHandling = MetadataPropertyHandling.Ignore
                });

            return Task.FromResult<IActionResult>(this.Ok(openApiDocument));
```

If you check the inner properties of the **OpenApiSchema** type there is a **Default** property of type **IOpenApiAny**.

Now the serialization part works great, but I'm having trouble deserializing the whole document because I get an exception like so:

*{"Error converting value "HelloDarknessMyOldFriend" to type 'Microsoft.OpenApi.Any.IOpenApiAny'.line 1, position 3065."}*

The deserialization code looks like this:

```
                var stream = httpClient.GetAsync(urlBuilder.ToString()).Result;
                stream.EnsureSuccessStatusCode();
                responseBody = stream.Content.ReadAsStringAsync().Result;

                var swagger = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<OpenApiDocument>(responseBody, new JsonSerializerSettings()
                {
                    MetadataPropertyHandling = MetadataPropertyHandling.Ignore,
                });
```

How can I somehow help the `deserialization` of the whole `OpenApiDocument` so I won't get an exception because There are some `IOpenApiAny` properties in usage?

You can simulate the issue with the following code:

the two nugets I've used are:

```
<PackageReference Include="Microsoft.OpenApi" Version="1.2.3" />
<PackageReference Include="Newtonsoft.Json" Version="12.0.3" />
```

```
                var document = new OpenApiDocument();
                var schema = new OpenApiSchema();
                schema.Default = new OpenApiString("Hello");
                document.Components = new OpenApiComponents();
                document.Components.Schemas.Add("someSchema", schema);
                //Serializing 
                string serializedOpenApiDocument = document.Serialize(OpenApiSpecVersion.OpenApi3_0, OpenApiFormat.Json);
                //Deserializing - throws an exception
                var swagger = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<OpenApiDocument>(serializedOpenApiDocument, new JsonSerializerSettings());
```

Thanks in advance,

Comment: does your class HelloDarknessMyOldFriend implements IOpenApiAny?

Comment: on the service side I've done the following:

```uiSchema.Default = new OpenApiString("HelloDarknessMyOldFriend")```

OpenApiString derived from OpenApiPrimitive<T> which implements IOpenApiAny

Comment: if you could post minimal amount of code to duplicate this issue locally would help

Comment: Added a snippet to easily reproduce the issue with a simple console application above.

Answer (score 0):

[JsonSerializerDataContractResolver](https://github.com/domaindrivendev/Swashbuckle.AspNetCore/blob/master/src/Swashbuckle.AspNetCore.SwaggerGen/SchemaGenerator/JsonSerializerDataContractResolver.cs)

```
_serializerDataContractResolver = new JsonSerializerDataContractResolver(new JsonSerializerOptions());

var headersObject = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Dictionary<string, OpenApiHeaderExtend>>(headers);
response.Headers = headersObject.ToDictionary(
    ho => ho.Key, 
    ho =>
    {
        var type = ho.Value.Schema.Example.GetType();
        var dataContract = _serializerDataContractResolver.GetDataContractForType(type);
        var exampleAsJson = dataContract.JsonConverter(ho.Value.Schema.Example);
        
        return new OpenApiHeader
        {
            Description = ho.Value.Description,
            Schema = new OpenApiSchema
            {
                Type = ho.Value.Schema.Type,
                Example = OpenApiAnyFactory.CreateFromJson(exampleAsJson)
            }
        };
    });


public class OpenApiHeaderExtend : OpenApiHeader
{
    public new OpenApiSchemaExtend Schema { get; set; }
}

public class OpenApiSchemaExtend : OpenApiSchema
{
    public new object Example { get; set; }
}
```